# React Router pathes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App component contains Navbar.
Page component contains main.
Idea - to show App component and page components together when the url is 'localhost:3000/authentication'
But when I am on this url - it shows navbar only.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="authentication" element={<Authentication />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById("root")

);
```

But when I do it without nesting it shows me App on '/' url and Auth on 'auth' url:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}/ >
      <Route path="authentication" element={<Authentication />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById("root")
```

First example should work, but he doesn't. Using useNavigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App` component should also render an `Outlet` component for the nested `Route` components to be rendered into.

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
  </>
);
```

...

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="authentication" element={<Authentication />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```